# How can I create a grid using input functions in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, input, grid, cell

I have to create the Game of Life with tkinter, but I'm stuck at the graphical part.

Specifically, the one about creating a grid with n x n and with active cells σ*n*n, with the values n and σ given by user input.

After some researches in the documentations and tutorials, I managed to write the following code in Python 3:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
grid = Grid()


mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)


N1 = int(input("Inserisci numero per il lato: "))
lato = []
for row in range(N1):
    for column in range(N1):
        lato = Frame(root, bg='white', highlightbackground="black",                          highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1,                          width=50, height=50, padx=3, pady=3)
        lato.grid(row=row, column=column)

N2 = int(input("Inserisci numero percentuale griglia: "))
celle = []
for i in range(1, int(N2**0.5)+1):
    if N2 % i == 0:
       celle.append(i)
       celle.append(N2//i)
       if 0 < N2 < 1:
           griglia = [i2*(i1*2) for i1, i2 in zip(celle,lato)]
           griglia.place(bg="grey", width=30, height=30, padx=1, pady=1)



root.mainloop()
```

So far, the code creates the grid thanks to the list method, but I cannot create the sigma cells over the grid, like there were invisible or non-existent.

My idea was to create the grid with the n x n and then add inactive cells for the Game of Life with the sigma value.

Of course the program will use the Turtle module to go to the cells and fill them with colour according to the cells' lifespan, but I need to nail the cells down before tackling that out with Turtle and Thread module.

How can I do this?

Comment: `lato` becomes an instance of `Frame` after the first for loop.  `N2` is an integer, so `0 < N2 < 1` is always `False`.  `griglia` is a list, so it does not have a `place()` function. So it is hard to understand what your code does.

Comment: I was trying to create a grid with different coloured cells thanks to those input functions, but I can't wrap those into the window.
Maybe I should rewrite the code in Class-object, but I wish to nail the functions down before doing that.